# Errors from "easy_install zeromq"?

Tags: installation, zeromq

Apparently this is a known problem but I'm relatively new to installing stuff on Linux so I don't know what I'm supposed to do.  Can someone help explain what I should do differently?

The problem:

When I run "easy_install zeromq" I get this error.

```
Error running version detection script:

detect/vers: error while loading shared libraries: libzmq.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Fatal: 
    Failed to run ZMQ test program.  Please check to make sure:

    You have a C compiler installed
    A development version of Python is installed (including header files)
    A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including header files)
    If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
    If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location, 
      try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
      or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`
```

I found these links online:

http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-November/007545.html

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/05/23/building-zeromq-and-pyzmq-on-red-hat/

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2010-March/005900.html

What am I supposed to do?  I've tried a bunch of stuff from those links but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: Do you have the 0MQ libraries and header files installed?

Comment: Did you, and if so how, install zeromq prior to installing pyzmq?  The most common error if you just did a source install of zeromq is to skip `sudo ldconfig`, which tells ld to update its cache of what is available.

Answer (score 4):

If you continue having problems, take a look at the output of the command

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v | grep libzmq
```

If ldconfig did his job, you should see something like

```
libzmq.so.1 -> libzmq.so.1.0.1
```

If not, then maybe ldconfig doesn't scan /usr/local/lib, where libzmq is located.
To make it scan /usr/local/lib too do the following, su edit `/etc/ld.so.conf`, add at the end of the file

```
/usr/local/lib
```

and save.

Then `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v | grep libzmq` should rebuild the cache including zmq too.

Answer (score 1):

This recipe works for me:

```
cd ~
wget http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-2.1.11.tar.gz
tar zxvf zeromq-2.1.11.tar.gz
cd zeromq-2.1.11
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

pip install pyzmq
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom installation of ZeroMQ installed, you can give "pip" that information when trying to install the 'pyzmq' package.

I installed my ZeroMQ here: $HOME/.local/, so I ran the following pip command:
    pip install --install-option="--zmq=$HOME/.local" pyzmq

The "--install-option" forwards whatever you type in there to the "python setup.py install" command.